# iOS 10 ScrollView Not Working

Tags: ios, scrollview, ios10

New iOS developer, have been following an iOS 9 course on Pluralsight and very simply need to be able to put some Labels in a ScrollView. All I did was select all of the labels and a button and clicked

Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Which worked in the iOS 9 demo. I'm wondering if there is something different about iOS 10 that is not working. When I deploy to the app the labels show but you can't scroll. And yes I know how to scroll in the simulator.

I do see some warnings (which were present in the demo as well). I resolved a couple of them but still didn't work:

[image]

Comment: It's likely the warning `Has ambiguous scrollable content height` (or width if you're scrolling horizontally)

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Reset to suggested constraint" option.Which is situated at right bottom corner in the storyboard.

You are not able to scroll because of the constraint so just override the viewDidLayoutSubviews() method into the respective viewController and provide the contentSize to the scrollView

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1600.0)
}
```

Comment: thank you, i was looking for a solution for so long and did this the trick!